# Disable image tooltip when hovering property in css

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Anyone know if we can disable the tooltip in this screen shot? It is so annoying. When I move my cursor up to edit another property this obtrusive popup shows because my mouse hovered over that path. I basically have to move my cursor around the URL in order to avoid it and cannot close it without my mouse leaving the area.

[image]